# In ckeditor 3.4.1 I have a "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: ckeditor

When I loaded into a long html. I have a problem "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".

Comment: Is there anything more? A [stack trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) or something? `Maximum call stack size exceeded` can be anything - your code, ckeditor or other lib code

Comment: Thank you. But I'm not resolved that.